# Capture dragend event after element is removed

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drag

Is it possible to capture the dragend event if the element is removed from the DOM? The scenario would be is a user was dragging some element and then moved outside of the browser window and let go. However, before he lets go, the element is removed.

I'm guessing this is not feasible.